# Group variables in a dataframe R using a specific list

Tags: r, list, variables, grouping, aggregate

I have the following lists:

```
  group1<-c("A", "B", "D")
  group2<-c("C", "E")
  group3<-c("F")
```

and a dataframe with values and corresponding names:

```
  df <- data.frame (name=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
  df
    name value
  1    A     1
  2    B     2
  3    C     3
  4    D     4
  5    E     5
  6    F     6
```

I'd like to group the data based on the lists, using the name column;

```
  df
    name value    group
  1    A     1   group1
  2    B     2   group1
  3    C     3   group2
  4    D     4   group1
  5    E     5   group2
  6    F     6   group3
```

and sum the values for each group.

```
  df
       group sum
  1   group1   7
  2   group2   8
  3   group3   6
```

I've searched for similar posts, but failed using them for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach. First, use `ifelse` to assign groups to each `name`, then use `aggregate` to get the sum for each `group`.

```
> df$group <- with(df, ifelse(name %in% group1, "group1",
                              ifelse(name %in% group2, "group2", "group3" )))
> aggregate(value ~ group, sum, data=df)
   group value
1 group1     7
2 group2     8
3 group3     6
```

Comment: One more question then, let's say the initial df contains multiple value columns (value1, value2, value2), what's the best way to apply aggregate to all the columns.

Comment: try `aggregate(cbind(value1,value2,...,valueN) ~ group, sum, data=df)`

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
df$X <- factor(df$name)
levels(df$X) <- list(group1 = group1, group2 = group2, group3 = group3)
aggregate(df$value, list(group = df$X), sum)
#   group x
#1 group1 7
#2 group2 8
#3 group3 6
```

**EDIT**

As noted by @thelatemail in the comments below you can `mget` -in a list- all the objects in your workspace called "group_", like this:

```
mget(ls(pattern="group\\d+"))
```

In case, though, you have loaded -say- a function called "group4", this function will be selected too in `ls()`. A way to avoid this is to use something like:

```
.ls <- ls(pattern="group\\d+")
mget(.ls[!.ls %in% apropos("group", mode = "function")])  #`mget` only non-functions.
                                                      #You can, of course, avoid any 
                                                     #other `mode`, besides "function".
```

The list returned from `mget` can, then, be used as the `levels(df$X)`.

Comment: I think this is the most R-ish way to approach the problem and is very concise. The requirement to construct the named list could be avoided with something like: `levels(df$X) <- mget(ls(pattern="group\\d+"))`

Comment: @thelatemail: Ha, exactly what I was thinking! But when I used `pattern = "group"`, a function of mine that was loaded, called `groupby`, was returned too, and then I didn't spend more time on it. Your idea, though, of `grep`ping "group" followed by a digit is the best option. I'll edit my answer with a workaround I made, but feel free to edit if you have something better to add. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having your grouping as a data.frame, something along these lines -

```
grouping <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),groupno=c(1,1,1,2,2,3))
df2 <- merge(df,grouping, by = 'name')
aggregate(value ~ groupno, sum, data=df2)
```